# What does dominant generation mean

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, plant-anatomy

In my texbook it is written that for non- vascular seedless plants the dominant generation  is the gametophyte as the gametophyte generation is larger and longer lived.
Is the criteria for dominant generation?-( Which generation the plant spends most of its life in?)

Answer (score 1):

According to "Wile, Dr. Jay L. Exploring Creation With Biology. Apologia Educational Ministries, Inc. 1998" and reported [here](http://www.conservapedia.com/Dominant_generation),

> In alternation of generations, the dominant generation is the generation that occupies the largest portion of the life cycle

I guess that it has to be understood in terms of "time". I am not quite sure though if it has to be understood in terms of [generation time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_time) of life span. Intuitively, I would say that generation time would make much more sense. Therefore, I'd say that, **the dominant generation is the generation which have the longest mean generation time** (=mean time from the birth to reproduction).

As @Shigeta said in the comments: For example, in Homo sapiens, the dominant generation is the diploid phase (sporophyte, you and me) and the non-dominant generation is the haploid phase  (gametophyte, sperm/ovule).

Comment: an example is the human animal, which is dominant over the gamete (sperm/egg) generation.

Answer (score 1):

The wikipedia page [Alternation of Generations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternation_of_generations) actually has a pretty sophisticated discussion of this issue, and discusses the fact that plants can and do fall at a lot of different places on a gradient of one generation being dominant over another.

I think the root of this complexity is that this is an issue of terminology, and is connected to your concept of "what is an organism", which is a complex issue in and of itself (see [this answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/9148/3952)).

Despite this, I think that you can still usefully discuss use a number of criteria which argue for a generation being more or less dominant, including generation time, but also:

1) **size** (as you say in your question)

2) **morphological complexity**

3) **ability to independently undergo "life" processes** like photosynthesis and mitosis

4) **conspicuousness/salience to humans** (as we're the ones making up these categories)

Comment: I should also link to @Remi.b's answer to OPs other question, which is very similar: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/14186/sporophyte-and-gametophyte